# RestTemplate getForObject special characters into URL parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding, resttemplate

I am having problems when I try to call an endpoint using GET and passing a parameter into URL with special character like 'ñ':

Example:

```
parameters.add("name", "Añisc");
Person person = rest.getForObject(url.toUri(), Person.class, parameters);
```

Returns:

```
Error 502, Bad gateway
```

I've been reading possible solutions but none works for me. What can I do to send special characters in a property way?. I think that getForObject and url.toUri does the necessary encoding...

I have tried adding the following to tomcat config without luck:

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the other method of RestTemplate:

```
    final String oUrl = "http://myhost/name/{name}";
    final URI expanded = new UriTemplate(url).expand("Añisc");
    final String fUrl = URLDecoder.decode(expanded.toString(), "UTF-8");
    restTemplate.getForObject(fUrl, Object.class);
```

I mean, explading the URL yourself and put your desired encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String query = "Añisc";
String uri = "http://localhost:8081/"; // example
String path = "name" //example

URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
            .path(path)
            .queryParam("name", query)
            .build()
            .toUri();

restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, Person.class);
```